# What you mean by Off-Chain in Ethereum Blockchain? can i use geth as off-chain in DApp?

Tags: go-ethereum, dapps, off-chain

I have read several articles of off-chain definition and come to know that they are use for scale the ethereum blockchain. but my question is what is actually mean by off-chain word in ethereum blockchain? can i use geth as a off-chain for DApp? how i start to implement off-chain in DApp project? or off-chain means any local database? i am totally confused and gone through many articles in last three days. please help me to find out this answers and it will really helpful your suggestion to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's a matter of terminology, so it is probably subjected to interpretation.

When I say *off-chain*, I refer to the operation of calling a contract function **NOT** from another contract function, but from a web3-based script or application which communicates with a node on the Ethereum blockchain network.

This operation can be either one of the following:

1. A remote procedure call (RPC), which does not change anything on the blockchain, and therefore does not require signing it
2. A transaction, which does change some data the blockchain, and therefore does require signing it